# Cloud Firestore error, FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with Spring boot and Spring security to build a back end application, I am storing users into Cloud Firestore NonRelational Database, I am using an Admin SDK token provided by Google on the Firebase platform. I am initializing my Firestore in the following way.

```
@Service
public class UserFirestoreInitialize {
    
    @Value("classpath:static/gamingplatform-c922d-firebase-adminsdk-c25o8-06e92edfd5.json")
    Resource resourceFile;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            InputStream serviceAccount = resourceFile.getInputStream();
            GoogleCredentials cred = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)
                                        .createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore");
            FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                    .setCredentials(cred)
                    .setDatabaseUrl("FIREBASE_URL")
                    .build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I also had a Configuration class which looks like this.

```
@Configuration
public class UserFirestoreConfiguration{
    @Bean
    public Firestore getFirestore(){
        return FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
    }
}
```

After this, I could easily use this bean in my UserService as follows:

```
@Service
public class UserService{
    
    @Autowired
    private Firestore firestore;

    public User getUser(){
        //Query for user.
    }
    //Post, Put, delete
}
```

This worked at some point. The problem came when I added Spring Security into my applicatio. When I ran a Maven Install, the application did not build, the problem looks like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtTokenFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceDetailsImpl' defined in file [/Users/igorzelaya/SoftwareDev/D1Gaming-User-Back-end1/target/classes/com/d1gaming/user/security/UserServiceDetailsImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [/Users/igorzelaya/SoftwareDev/D1Gaming-User-Back-end1/target/classes/com/d1gaming/user/user/UserService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.d1gaming.user.user.UserService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.
```

I have a tried to isolate the problem, I created the another project and tried connecting to my database like I did in the snippet above^, everything worked just fine, I then copied my configuration classes one by one, I figured my application started to crash the moment I added my JWT Token Filter class, this class looks like this

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserServiceDetailsImpl userDetailsService;
    
    @Override
    //Get authorization header and validate it.
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)throws ServletException, IOException, NullPointerException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if(jwt != null && jwtTokenUtil.validate(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtTokenUtil.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    
    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can notice on my stack trace shown above, the error starts on the dependencies injected in this class, the **jwtTokenUtil** class and the **UserDetailsImpl**
the JwtTokenUtil class is this:

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil {

    @Value("${app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;
    
    @Value("${app.jwtExpirationMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationMs;
    
    
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtTokenUtil.class);
    
    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {
        UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(userPrincipal.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();
    }
    
    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
                .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }
    
    
    public String getUserId(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
        return claims.getSubject().split(",")[0];
    }

    
    public String getUsername(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
        return claims.getSubject().split(",")[0];
    }

    public Date getExpirationDate(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
        return claims.getExpiration();
    }

    public boolean validate(String token) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        }
        catch(SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature - {}",e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token - {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token - {}",e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token - {}", e.getMessage());     
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token - {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The UserServiceDetailsImpl class:

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private String userId;
    
    private String userRealName;
    
    private String userName;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    private String userPassword;
    
    private String userEmail;
    
    private UserStatus userStatusCode;
    
    private Team userTeam;
    
    private Map<String,Object> userBilling;

    private String userCountry;
    
    private int userTokens;
    
    private double userCash;
    
    private Map<String, Object> userBirthDate;

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public UserDetailsImpl(String userId, String userRealName, String userName, String userPassword, String userEmail,
            UserStatus userStatusCode, Team userTeam, Map<String, Object> userBilling, String userCountry,
            int userTokens, double userCash, Map<String, Object> userBirthDate,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userRealName = userRealName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userStatusCode = userStatusCode;
        this.userTeam = userTeam;
        this.userBilling = userBilling;
        this.userCountry = userCountry;
        this.userTokens = userTokens;
        this.userCash = userCash;
        this.userBirthDate = userBirthDate;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }
    
    public static UserDetailsImpl build(User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getUserRoles().stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleType().name()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new UserDetailsImpl(user.getUserId(),user.getUserRealName(),user.getUserName(),user.getUserPassword(),user.getUserEmail()
                        ,user.getStatusCode(),user.getUserTeam(),user.getUserBilling(),user.getUserCountry(),
                        user.getUserTokens(),user.getUserCash(),user.getUserBirthDate(),authorities
                    );
    }
//Getters and setters
}
```

As you can see, these classes both have nothing to do with Firestore, At the moment I was pretty confused so I did the following. I noticed that for some strange reason the **@PostConstruct** annotation was not working, Spring was not initializing my initializeFirestore() method on the first snippet of code, so I placed a initialize() method directly on spring boot as follows:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class UserApplication(){
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Basically does the same as the initialize method mentioned before.
            UserFirestoreUtils.initialize(UserFirestoreUtils.getOptions());
            SpringApplication.run(D1GamingUserBackEnd1Application.class, args);
        }
    }
```

The interesting thing is that when I debugged this I had the following error:

```
    The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   jwtTokenFilter (field private com.d1gaming.user.security.UserServiceDetailsImpl com.d1gaming.user.security.JwtTokenFilter.userDetailsService)
┌─────┐
|  userServiceDetailsImpl defined in file [/Users/igorzelaya/SoftwareDev/D1Gaming-User-Back-end1/target/classes/com/d1gaming/user/security/UserServiceDetailsImpl.class]
↑     ↓
|  userService (field private org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder com.d1gaming.user.user.UserService.passwordEncoder)
↑     ↓
|  userSecurityConfiguration (field com.d1gaming.user.security.UserServiceDetailsImpl com.d1gaming.user.security.UserSecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService)
└─────┘
```

The weird thing is that when I run a Maven install on it, the stack trace is the same as the one I showed at the beginning of the question, I feel there is not enough documentation on Cloud Firestore and its normal considering it is "New", but still it was annoying because I couldn't find the "Right way" of doing this and Google Documentation was clearly not enough. I am sorry If I included way too much code, I think it is necessary, but anyways thank you for your time, I appreciate if anyone could help me. Have a nice day.

Comment: do you want to use only the firestore database or you are working with other firebase products?

Comment: Just Cloud Firestore

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a collision between Spring dependencies and Firebase Admin. You can try with [Firestore client library](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers#java). Firebase admin SDK is a wider library that some part of code can collision with Spring security